# Is it possible to display the x-axis values of the DataVisualization.Charting.Chart in hexadecimal?

Tags: c#, charts, label, hex, axis

Recently started using the Chart control included in .NET 4 in the DataVisualization.Charting namespace. I am working on a project where a delay value used in an FPGA is displayed on the x-axis of a line chart during calibrations. The value is used elsewhere as a hexadecimal value.

Was wondering if there is a way to display the x-axis labels in hexadecimal format. It's not vital as can simply convert values following runs with relative ease, but would certainly be an enhancement. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `LabelStyle` of the `Axis` objects have a `Format` property, so you can use any of the standard C# formatting strings. You can thus set

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "X4";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am getting a FormatException from the code:      chartCalibrate.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "x2";

Comment: This works fine. What are the values that throw the exception??